# Laravel use a pivot field to filter polymorphic many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm attaching user permissions to several different models using a polymorphic many-to-many relationship - the pivot table is called `permissables`:

```
Permissables
- id
- user_id
- permissable_type
- permissable_id
- role
- created_at
- updated_at
```

This is working well - I can return a list of permitted users for my `Project` model using:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'permissable')->withPivot('role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

If I want to filter this to just owners - ie where the pivot field `role` is equal to `owner` - I can do the following in Tinker:

```
Project::first()->users->where('pivot.role', '=', 'owner')
```

But if I try this in my model:

```
public function owners()
{
    return $this->users()->where('pivot.role', '=', 'owner');
}
```

when I call `Project->owners` in Tinker, I get an error:

```
>>> Project::first()->owners
[!] Aliasing 'Project' to 'App\Project' for this Tinker session.
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: pivot.role (SQL: select "users".*, "permissables"."permissable_id" as "pivot_permissable_id", "permissables"."user_id" as "pivot_user_id", "permissables"."permissable_type" as "pivot_permissable_type", "permissables"."role" as "pivot_role", "permissables"."created_at" as "pivot_created_at", "permissables"."updated_at" as "pivot_updated_at" from "users" inner join "permissables" on "users"."id" = "permissables"."user_id" where "permissables"."permissable_id" = 1 and "permissables"."permissable_type" = App/Project and "pivot"."role" = owner)'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For the first question:

```php
return $this->users->where('pivot.role', '=', 'owner');
```

This line works because `$this->users` return the **users' collection with pivot**(The key name is `pivot`). And you are using [where-method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where) to filter users **collection**.

#### For the second question:

`$this->users()` change the laravel code to raw sql like:

```sql
select users.*, permissables.permissable_id as pivot_permissable_id, permissables.user_id as pivot_user_id, permissables.permissable_type as pivot_permissable_type, permissables.role as pivot_role, permissables.created_at as pivot_created_at, permissables.updated_at as pivot_updated_at
from users 
inner join permissables on users.id = permissables.user_id 
where permissables.permissable_id = 1 and permissables.permissable_type = "App/Project"
```

So **the Intermediate Table** name is `permissables`, not `pivot`. Mysql cannot found the intermediate's column when applying `where('pivot.role', 'owner')` to `users()`.

Laravel provide `wherePivot` method, which will add intermediate table name for you.

```php
public function owners()
{
    return $this->users()->wherePivot('role', 'owner'); // change to where pemissables.role = 'owner'
}
```